# How to get the xml control attributes

Tags: javascript, xml, controls, sapui5

I want to get attributes in method `render`

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/Control"
], function (Control) {
    "use strict";
    return Control.extend("sap.ui.test.control.IndexPageButton", {
        metadata : {
            properties: {
                value:  {type : "float", defaultValue : 0},
                name: "IndexPageButton",
                label: "Label"
            },
            events: {},
            aggregations : {}
        },
        init : function () {
        },
        renderer : function (oRM, oControl) {
            oRM.write("<div");
            oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
            oRM.writeClasses();
            oRM.write(">");

            oRM.write("<span");
            oRM.addClass("label");
            oRM.write(">");
            oRM.write("</span>");

            oRM.write("<span");
            oRM.addClass("counter");
            oRM.write(">");
            oRM.write("</span>");

            oRM.write("</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

XML:

```
<test:IndexPageButton class="item" value="20" label="{i18n>homePageLink}" />
```

I want get attrs value and label, and paste them in render sapn's.

How i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the properties of a control via their respective getter function.

For each property that is defined in the metadata, the framework automatically generates a getter and a setter.

So you can access the value and the label in your `renderer` function with the following lines:

```
oControl.getValue();
oControl.getLabel();
```

Comment: Thank's! And how can I set an event on this item? If I add attribute `press="showAlert"` - it will not work.  Can you tell?

Comment: I think the control which you inherit from does not have any events yet. You have to add the event (e. g. `press`) in the metadata. Again, the `attach`, `detach` and `fire` method will be auto generated. @nabi made a nice tutorial on how to make a custom control, if you need further information: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/creating-custom-controls-in-sapui5